# Unable to fetch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

i have upgrade kibana 3 to kibana 4 and when go to dashboard, ask me an index patterno but i have the error:

> Unable to fetch mapping. Do you have indices matching the pattern?

The indices existing, kibana 3 working perfectly, if i get `curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices` i view the indices:

```
green open logstash.ced.prod-2015.09.01             5 1       1 0   10.2kb    5.2kb 
green open logstash.404.prod-2015.09.23             5 1     482 0    4.1mb      2mb 
green open logstash-prod-2015.09.01                 5 1   54549 0   53.8mb   26.9mb  
green open logstash.clesp.prod-2015.09.17           5 1    2831 0      1mb  548.5kb 
green open logstash-sql-prod-2015.08.27             5 1      24 0  294.5kb  147.2kb 
green open logstash-site-idp-2015.08.17             5 1    2400 0      2mb   1009kb
```

Is configured with proxypass and nginx (if it could be useful)

Comment: What are the index patterns you have in the settings->indices panel in kibana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved disabling the other directives to ngnix:

```
#  location ~ ^/_aliases$ {
#    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
#    proxy_read_timeout 90;
#  }
#  location ~ ^/.*/_aliases$ {
#    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
#    proxy_read_timeout 90;
#  }
#  location ~ ^/_nodes$ {
#    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
#    proxy_read_timeout 90;
#  }
#  location ~ ^/.*/_search$ {
#    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
#    proxy_read_timeout 90;
#  }
#  location ~ ^/.*/_mapping {
#    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
#    proxy_read_timeout 90;
#  }
#  location ~ ^/.*/_cluster$ {
#    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
#    proxy_read_timeout 90;
#  }
...
```

I have upgrade from kibana 3 and it's the old configuration of ngnix, i have commented all `location`